# subraction in mvc 4 from only 1 field of table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to do subtract "1" from table `bookinfo`'s field `available`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult issuebook(string type, string accessionno, string bookname, string issuedate, string duedate, string id)
{
    tblIssuedbook issuebook = new tblIssuedbook();
    issuebook.AccessionNo = accessionno;
    issuebook.Name = bookname;
    issuebook.IssueDate = issuedate;
    issuebook.DueDate = duedate;
    issuebook.Type = type;
    issuebook.MemberId = id;
    db.tblIssuedbooks.Add(issuebook);
    db.SaveChanges();
    Bookinfo b = new Bookinfo();
    return view();
}
```

I want when these field are saved in the db to subtract "1" from another table according to the `accessionNo`

Comment: Could you post your EF Context? We need more info to help you.

Comment: You need to first load the persisted entry, subtract 1 from it, then persist it back to the database.